# How to turn off specific Magento Crons for a development store?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, development

## Synopsis

I have a development environment which is a copy of the production system.  I would like to be able to turn off certain crons in this development environment so orders, products and the likes are not synchronised with third-parties.

I do however need certain crons to run, some of which are being developed within this environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you [this free extension by AOE](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler). it gives you an UI for managing crons.
One of the features is to disable any cron you want.

Comment: I did see this a lot, only I didn't realise what i seek is a feature. I shall give it a quick go. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ash. You should give it a try. It's a real life saver for developers and not only.

Comment: I've installed this and it solves the problem, I can see actually how useful it can be with Magento!